# file_get_contents returns a 400 error on same link?

Tags: php

when trying to use the below script I have a really annoying issue, that is that only the last "term"  from the for each loop appears to connect to the page, every other one generates a 400 bad request from the page, even when using the same URL twice in a row the first generates the 400 error, the last instance of it works as intended and returns the page (this stage is just for testing).

Does anyone know why this is? it's driving me mad right now that no matter what I try (including curl) has the same issue, I feel its something really stupid I've done wrong with the foreach loop but I just can't see it right now, any help with this would be appreciated.

```
<?PHP
  $terms = explode("\n",$_POST['term']);

   #print_r ($terms);

  foreach ($terms as $term)
        {
    print $term."<br>";



        $page = file_get_contents($term);
        print $page;



       }
```

Comment: what does `print $term` give you? or can you give an output of the script?

Comment: The print $term returns the links from the explode section & array as you would expect, so when using google for example returns the following:

    http://www.google.com 

<HTTP 400 Response Error > 

    http://www.google.com

    <Google Homepage>

Comment: Your script works fine for me (using php 5.3)

Comment: Weird, using PHP 5.2.9 here. It's doing my head in as anything that is done afterwards, such as to gather something from the site it will only do this on the last term sent through the form. With 2/3/4 etc. it will 400 error everything before the last, this is with a range of methods too as said not just file_get_contents